While importing the resources, I got an error message
azurerm_public_ip.TestGeraldVm: Importing from ID "C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/3476gjkfe7-73ed-3444-2124-n8e6ad00jr1z/resourceGroups/henry/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip"...
Error: parsing "C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/3476gjkfe7-73ed-3444-2124-n8e6ad00jr1z/resourceGroups/henry/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip": parsing segment "subscriptions": parsing the PublicIPAddress ID: the segment at position 0 didn't match
Expected a PublicIPAddress ID that matched:

/subscriptions/12345678-1234-9876-4563-123456789012/resourceGroups/example-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/publicIPAddressesValue

However this value was provided:

C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/3476gjkfe7-73ed-3444-2124-n8e6ad00jr1z/resourceGroups/henry/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip

The parsed Resource ID was missing a value for the segment at position 0
(which should be the literal value "subscriptions").
Tried to import the resources to delete the IP

If you want to import existing public details, you can use     terraform import azurerm_public_ip.example /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/venkatIP

The resource ID you're trying to import is incorrectly formatted. Azure expects a resource ID to start with /subscriptions/..., but the ID you provided starts with a local file path. This is causing Terraform to fail when parsing the ID.

terraform import azurerm_public_ip.example "subscriptions/3476gjkfe7-73ed-3444-2124n8e6ad00jr1z/resourceGroups/henry/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip"
this is the comment i have given in the terminal

What is the error with that command?

Error: parsing "C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/3476gjkfe7-73ed-3444-2124-n8e6ad00jr1z/resourceGroups/henry/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip": parsing segment "subscriptions": parsing the PublicIPAddress ID: the segment at position 0 didn't match
Expected a PublicIPAddress ID that matched:
/subscriptions/12345678-1234-9876-4563-123456789012/resourceGroups/example-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/publicIPAddressesValue
this is the error

Share the terraform import command your using?

try adding the leading "/" before "subscription/347..."

The Azure Public IP resource ID you're trying to import is incorrect format. the resource ID start with /subscriptions/..., but you provided local path in import command, because of this ID Terraform is throwing an error as incorrect ID.
Make sure to pass the correct resource ID in terraform import command.
You can find the azure public IP resource ID by navigating to Azure Public IP address > Select your IP > Overview > JSON View

  terraform import azurerm_public_ip.example /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/venkatIP

terraform import azurerm_public_ip.example Public IP resource ID


Same error continues..

terraform import azurerm_public_ip.TestVm /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddres ses/zzz I'm trying to delete the ip address from the existing resource using terraform

If you're on Windows machine and using Git Bash, this is due to POSIX to Windows conversion ruining the resource ID. The solution is to run the command before executing import:
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

